# Boy receives strange postal letters from an older man, trying to recruit him to save the world

Tags: story-identification

I read a book maybe 5-10 years ago that I’m trying to find. From what I remember the book is about a young male teen who keeps receiving strange letters in the mail. I believe he finds out they are coming from an older man who is trying to recruit him to help save the world.

Comment: I noticed that you tagged this as 'fantasy'. What was fantastical about it?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What was strange about the letters? Were they written on unusual materials? Used odd grammar? Glowed or suddenly disappeared upon reading? Were only readable by the boy?

Comment: The letters weren't addressed to "Mr H Potter, The Cupboard under the Stairs, 4 Privet Drive, Little Whinging, Surrey", were they?